# What is the difference between static and dynamic Azure files?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, persistent-storage

The official docs don't really explain these properly an I can barely find any other article that explains the difference. I would like to know when to use static or dynamic azure files.

In my case I have a Laravel app which has a feature that allows you to upload files. The app is deployed using azure Kubernetes service, therefore I have to create a Persistent Volume Claim to persist the uploaded files in the storage folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

static - would be a [precreated file share](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/aks/azure-files-volume#create-an-azure-file-share)
dynamic - would be created and managed by kubernetes for you

thats the difference between dynamic and static

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/